# Why doesn't the inner dropper reflect properly?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials

[image]

May I know how do I get the inner tube that's in the liquid to show some sort of transparency as well?

For the glass bottle, I have 2 faces for it, 1 with the normals facing outwards at 1.45 IOR ( Glass To Air ), and the inner facing which is slightly smaller in scale with its normal facing inwards towards the liquid at 1.10 ( Glass To Liquid )
Followed by the liquid itself with its normals facing outwards at 1.33 IOR ( Liquid To Air )

However, I thought the glass tube would be able to reflect with the inverse IOR or 0.9 or so for liquid to glass but it isn't working

Could someone kindly advise me on this?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Which renderer are you using? Have you run out of light-bounces in Cycles?

Comment: @RobinBetts I'm using cycles, and thank you so much kind stranger... I doubled my tranmission lights and it worked haha shame it never occurred to me, thanks so much!!!